# How can i remove the rectangle created in android?

Tags: android

I have created a rectangle on button click like this

```
 public void createRectangle(View view) {
        Rectangle tmp = new Rectangle(this, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        listRect.add(tmp);
        frame.addView(tmp, idFrame);
        idFrame++;
 }
```

I dont know how to remove this created rectangle on another button click. Can anyone post the solution?

Edit

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     x = event.getX();
     y = event.getY(); 
     if (inside(mx, my)) { }  
     for (int i = 0; i < listRectangle.size(); i++) { 
         if (listRectangle.get(i).inside(mx, my))  { 
               index = i; 
         } 
     } 
     listRectangle.remove(index); 
}
```

Comment: how do you decide which rectangle do you want to remove when you click on the other button ?

Comment: public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {   
   x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
   if (inside(mx, my)) {
   }
   index = -1;
   for (int i = 0; i < listRect.size(); i++) {
    if (listRect.get(i).inside(mx, my)) {
     index = i;
    }
   }
   listRect.remove(index);
   }
I am doing like this. I dont what I doing is right or wrong as this is my first work in Android.

Comment: remove returns a `Rectangle`, in your case. `Rectangle r = listRectangle.remove(index); frame.removeView(r);` should do it. If onTouch is overridden in `frame`, than it is just `removeView(r)`

Comment: Sorry, Its giving error

Comment: 2064-2064/com.shema.example.schema E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
    2064-2064/com.shema.example.schema E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
    2064-2064/com.shema.example.schema E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
            at com.shema.example.schema.Main.onTouchEventMoveRectangle(Main.java:214)

Comment: edit your question, adding the code that is causing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SparseArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) rather than linked list and store element at you idFrame index. You can then delete it from SparseArray and from ViewGroup using idFrame index.